# Rewrite no subdomain to www and take into consideration http(s)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an .htaccess file that redirects a user to the www subdomain if there is no subdomain, however I want to also take into consideration if they are accessing via http or https.

How can I redirect to the correct protocol?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` for https or `off`. Is your above `%{HTTP_HOST}` regex working correctly?

Comment: A user can either enter via http or https, I don't want to force them to either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this modified rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```